# Is there a way that Azure Data Factory Pipeline step to execute automatic retry if the step failed?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

By the step, I mean each copy, each filter, each columns, or each sink. I have a hard time figuring it out because I only know how to re-run the whole pipeline but not the individual steps inside pipeline. The re-run of each step is to determine th intermittent errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Activity Policies available **only** for execution activities ([data movement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities?tabs=data-factory#data-movement-activities) and [data transformation activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities?tabs=data-factory#data-transformation-activities))

This property includes a timeout and retry behavior.

> [image]

For more information, see official MS doc on [Activity policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities?tabs=data-factory#activity-policy)

Comment: Does it re-execute the only activity where it fails? Like when I have 4 activities is a pipeline and the 3rd activity got the error. The automated re-execute starts at 3rd pipeline again.