# How to check the status of pipeline A from Pipeline B. I have to pass the status of Pipeline A into If activity in pipeline B

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to check the status of pipeline A from Pipeline B. I have to pass the status of Pipeline A into If activity in pipeline B

I have created a pipeline A which has 3 databricks notebook and on Pipeline B i have to use If activity and pass the status of pipeline A. On False condition i have to rerun the pipeline A.
Is there any way through which I can check the status of pipeline through code/activity so that I can pass that inside the if condition.

Flow of Pipeline B will look like this:
If activity :
Pipeline A executes unsuccessful:
Rerun it
Otherwise:
Add wait activity

Comment: Does Pipeline A have 3 separate databricks activities to execute the notebooks? If so, if the failure is in notebook 2, do you really need to start from the beginning and run notebook 1 again? If not, then you can make use of the retry facility in the execute notebook activity itself.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106117/is-there-a-way-that-azure-data-factory-pipeline-step-to-execute-automatic-retry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you want to execute the pipeline A (P_A) as long as it runs unsuccessfully, you can use until loop and a flag variable to achieve this requirement.
- I have set a flag variable with value as `false` to begin with.

[image]

- Inside until, I have my pipeline A (P_A), if it fails, then I would use another set variable activity and set it value to `false` itself.
- If the pipeline A runs successfully, then I set flag variable value to true and thus stopping the until loop.

[image]

- The following is a pipeline JSON structure you can follow as a template for your pipeline B.

```
{
    "name": "P_B",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "flag",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "true",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Until1",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@not(equals(variables('flag'),'false'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "P_A",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable3",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "flag",
                                "value": "true"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set variable4",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Execute Pipeline1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Failed"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "flag",
                                "value": "false"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Wait1",
                "type": "Wait",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Until1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "waitTimeInSeconds": 10
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "flag": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the second image, give the failure branch to set variable activity where you can assign the value `false`. The success branch can be given to another set variable activity to assign the value `true`

Comment: but has one problem if the P_A is running successfully then inside until loop it will run again n again

Comment: If P_A runs successfully, flag becomes true. until will run only if flag is not equal to true

Comment: Ok but you mentioned false here : value": "@not(equals(variables('flag'),'false'))

Comment: The condition helps to iterate the loop as long as the flag is false. When P_A runs successfully, it will stop. Reference image: https://i.imgur.com/WW9y6AL.png

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can create a master pipeline for the whole requirement

1. Create a variable and assign the default value as 'False'
2. Use execute pipeline activity to execute PipelineA . Set Waitoncompletion to True
3. Connect it to Set variable activity via 'on completion' (green) arrow
4. Set the status variable to 'True' in the set variable activity
5. Connect it with If activity via 'on completion' path (blue)
6. In If activity , check if 'status' variable is true
7. In true block call pipeline B via execute pipeline activity
8. In false block, use web activity to call the rest API to run pipeline A again

Here is the link for rest api to run a pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?tabs=HTTP

Comment: where you created rhe first step in video?